# Invalid field isActive for SObject User in trigger (before update)

Tags: trigger, user, invalid

Can you please help me figure out why is the following code giving this error:

> UserBU : UserBU: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: line 9, column 21: Invalid field isActive for SObject User.

The problem is with the line

```
if(trigger.old[i].isActive)
```

Trigger:

```
trigger UserBU on User (before update) 
{
    // set deactive time
    integer i = 0;

    for(User u : trigger.new)
    {
        if(!u.isActive) 
        if(trigger.old[i].isActive) 
        u.User_Deactivated_DateTime__c = system.now();

        if(!u.isActive && u.User_Deactivated_DateTime__c == null) u.User_Deactivated_DateTime__c = system.now();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of profile does the context user have?

Comment: Have a look at this post here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T45SAAS We are having this same issue on one of our User triggers and apparently they are getting fired when you open up the developer console. I verified that this error was occurring immediately when opening up the developer console in one of our problem sandboxes. Our specific error message: execution of BeforeUpdate
caused by: line 28, column 17: Invalid field ProfileId for SObject User

Comment: Instead of using i, please try if(Trigger.oldMap.get(u.id).isActive == TRUE)